# Crime and Punishments - Apologies in Advance

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

You know the drill man!

Place the tiles to find the eight-letter solutions to the clues

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I got:

> [image]

Since the clues are question-marked, and the [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) tag *is* there, the words are

> Monastic - like a monk -> monk-ey
>  Agnostic - Doesn't know if there's a god -> not monk-like
>  Stagnate - Cease (growing, for example)

Comment: Your interpretation of "monkey" seems rot13(zber pbeerpgrl) than mine.

Comment: Haven't had two answers before - but this is the intended one

Answer (score 11):

The tiles should be placed like this

> [image]

*MONKEY?*

> An AGNOSTIC believes we may be related to monkeys.

*NOT MONKEY?*

> A MONASTIC believes in Creationism.

*CEASE*

> STAGNATE means to stop.

Comment: This answer actually makes more direct sense, at least to me.

Comment: It may be that many rot13(zbaxf) believe in both of those things and don't consider them incompatible. I like the other answer better.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon It may be. I wasn't positing my theological opinion, just trying to make sense of the puzzle.